Both if-else block is getting executed
I have made session manager in this activity . If the user is logged in , then It will be redirected to the Home Activity and if not then to the fragment EmailSignIn But somehow , Both the blocks of if else is getting executed when user is logged in. Please look into this .
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    val currentUser = mAuth.currentUser
    if (currentUser != null) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    } else{
        val signIn = EmailSignIn()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.logFragment, signIn)
            commit()
        }
    }
}

}

implement log in the code , only if block will be executed if user is logged in and else when not logged in .

What told you that both blocks are executed?

@Rudra in logcat , logs of both blocks are printed

@RickyMo Yes , both of them

@LakshayKadam you could have been using fragment on the screen by default and and when the compiler goes  to if block , it  redirects you to another screen or activity . implement Log.d("TAG,"Location : message") inside your code.

I cannot see any log statements in your code. Please edit your question and add all the code and tell us why you think that both parts of the if statement are triggered.

@AlexMamo I  had put breakpoints at both transitions and when i had put debugger , both breakpoints where encountered

There is no way in which both parts of the if statement are triggered. Can you please explain in detail how did you debug that?

basically , when If block is executed then it leads to HomeActivity where user data is stored and when stored it shows log indicating that data is stored and if else is executed then emailSIgnIn Fragment occurs and user is asked to login through various login but it is going both to emailSignIn fragment and to data is also stored

Theres no possiblility of both blocks to be executed. Your account creation logic probably is not properly implemented. Whats the code for EmailSignin() fragment?

Sounds like you have a bug somewhere else in your code and you think it's in the code you posted. You need to debug your app

As others said, for each time onCreate runs only the if block or the else block will get executed. There is no way for both of them to be executed on a single run of onCreate.
What is most likely is that your MainActivity is getting constructed twice: once before Firebase has restored the user from local storage, and once after it has restored that user. So the first time it executes the if part of your code, and the second time it executes the else part.
If that is indeed happening, it is the expected behavior of currentUser. An auth state listener might provide a path forward: Listen for authentication state in Android.
